# Reading an integer and then 3 structures from a binary file in C

Tags: c, struct, integer, binaryfiles, fread

I want to read from a .bin file that I wrote. I wrote an integer and 3 structures in a .bin file. When I try to read from it, I get an error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'A' was corrupted. occurred
```

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct videoteka {
char naslov[50];
char glumac[50];
char vrsta[40];
long int rBroj;
}FILM;
```

This is how I wrote to my .bin file: *FIXED AND WRITTEN TO THE FILE AGAIN*

```
int main()
{
FILM* film = malloc(3 * sizeof(*film));
strcpy(film[0].naslov, "Nana");
strcpy(film[0].glumac, "Goran");
strcpy(film[0].vrsta, "Komedija");
film[0].rBroj = 123456;
strcpy(film[1].naslov, "Blabla");
strcpy(film[1].glumac, "Mirko");
strcpy(film[1].vrsta, "Horor");
film[1].rBroj = 6467347;
strcpy(film[2].naslov, "Tanana");
strcpy(film[2].glumac, "Ivan");
strcpy(film[2].vrsta, "Drama");
film[2].rBroj = 8421841;

FILE* fPt = fopen("filmovi.bin", "wb");
int n = 3;
fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, fPt);
fwrite(&film, sizeof(FILM), 3, fPt);
fclose(fPt);
return 0;
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to read from it:

```
FILM* ucitavanjeFilmova(char fileName[20], int n)
{
FILM *(A[3]);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    A[i] = (FILM*)malloc(sizeof(FILM));
FILE* fPt = fopen(fileName, "rb");
fseek(fPt, 5, SEEK_SET);
fread(&A, sizeof(FILM), 3, fPt);
fclose(fPt);
return A;
}
```

I am first trying to allocate memory for n(in this case 3) structures of type FILM. Then I am trying to read 3 structures and store them to the adress of pointer A. After that I return pointer A. I am using fseek because one integer is written to the file before all structures.

Comment: For one thing, `FILM *(film[3]);` should be `FILM *film[3];` The array for the reading process does not match the array used for output anyway. When reading, the three `malloc`s all write to the same variable `A`.

Comment: Does that mean that my .bin file was not even written to correctly?
The .bin file was not written in this program code I am asking about. It was written on the first block of code I posted above. Could it be possible that it did not write structures correctly to the .bin file at the first place? Corrected A to A[i], still gives me the same error..

Comment: @WeatherVane difference ?

Comment: I suggest that in a case like this with just 3 records(well advised!) you can inspect the output file with a file dump tabulator.

Comment: Read your compiler warnings

Comment: Seems to me you are writing pointers to the file... bad

Comment: `FILM *(film[3]);` is one pointer which points to an array of 3 elements. `FILM *film[3];` is an array of three pointers to your `struct`s.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think so.. the ( ) should be placed otherwise. Here they mean nothing

Comment: If you have more code please add it to the question. Only one-liners are legible in comment.

Comment: @4386427 please post a meaningful/helpful comment. The `()` should not even be there, not "placed otherwise".

Comment: @WeatherVane `FILM *(film[3]);` is an array of pointers to int. And `FILM *film[3];` is just the same.If you want something different the syntax is `FILM (*film)[3];`

Comment: Can you confirm that the .bin file was written to as it was intended? I wanted to write an integer n, and then 3 structures initialized in the code. My .bin file is 436 bytes large.

Comment: @PatrikMakaj We can confirm that the is NOT written correctly.

Comment: Learn about [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) and perhaps [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: Can someone then write me a code to write those 3 structs to my .bin file. I think my structures are good, because when I use printf("%d", film[1]->rBroj); and others, it displays the correct value. The problem is somewhere in the fwrite() I guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fwrite`, you need to pass it a pointer to the things you want to write. But you don't do that. You pass it a pointer to `FILM`, which is an array of pointers and definitely not the thing you want to write to the file!

Since you need to write three different blocks of memory to the file, you need to call `fwrite` three times. Each time, pass it a pointer to a single `FILM` object.

Similarly, your `fread` overwrites the pointers to the memory you allocated. You need to call `fread` three times, each time passing it a pointer to one of the blocks you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem start here:

```
fwrite(&(film[3]), sizeof(FILM), 3, fPt);
```

Sorry.. but that's all wrong.

Look here:

```
FILM *(film[3]);
```

So what is `film` ? It's an array of 3 pointers to `FILM`. So even accessing `film[3]` is wrong. You can access `film[0]`, `film[1]`, `film[2]` but `film[3]` ! nope.

The fact is that you don't want an array of 3 pointers to `FILM` - you want 3 `FILM` in one array.

So simply do:

```
FILM film[3];
```

and forget the `malloc` stuff

Then your write just goes:

```
fwrite(film, sizeof(FILM), 3, fPt);
```

**EDIT**

There seem to be some confusion here about the syntax. So:

```
FILM *(film[3]);
FILM *film[3];
FILM* film[3];
```

are **identical** statements. They are all: `film` is an array of 3 pointers to `FILM`.

That is **not** what you want.

What you want is - in the simple form:

```
FILM film[3];
...
fwrite(film, sizeof *film, 3, fPt);
```

If you want `malloc` you can do it in several ways. The simple way is:

```
FILM *film = malloc(3 * sizeof *film);
```

The more "special" way is

```
FILM (film*)[3] = malloc(sizeof *film);
...
fwrite(film, sizeof *film, 1, fPt);
```

And for the syntax part:

```
FILM (film*)[3]
```

means **pointer to array containing 3 FILM**

Comment: @PatrikMakaj Nope `FILM *(film[3]);` is just the the same as `FILM *film[3];` And that is **not** what you want. If you want to deal with pointers and `malloc` you need `FILM (*film)[3]` but again - not what you want - much more complicated.

Comment: I need to use it as a pointer because I am using it in a function which returns the adress of those 3 structures which I need to use further in the program. So I can not forget the malloc stuff because it can't be a local struct.

Comment: And I think that `FILM*(film[3]);`  works just fine, because it is a pointer to an array of structs. And I am not sure if I use the `&(film[3])`, does that use the adress of the first struct and writes a block of 3*sizeof(FILM) in bytes to the file.

Comment: @PatrikMakaj No!!! `FILM*(film[3]);` is **not** a pointer to an array of struct. If you want that then `FILM (*film)[3]` is a pointer to an array of struct with three elements

Comment: Can you help me rewrite the code so the integer and 3 structs write correctly to the .bin file? I am not sure how to do it by myself. Thanks anyways.